# Android Studio - How do I get documents from a sub-collection in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get documents in a sub-collection where the date=DATE and title=TITLE in a document. I'm using date and title as primary keys so that I can display information from the documents from sub-collection "bulletin". How would I do that in Android Studio?

Or would it be better to use a different structure?

Thanks!

[Image - Firestore Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO8FK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please understand that SO is not a project completing site, you're free to post question where you are finding some difficulty, but avoid just asking the question without showing what you've tried for the problem.

Comment: I apologize. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference bulletinRef = rootRef.collection("bulletin");
bulletinRef.whereEqualTo("date", date).whereEqualTo("title", title).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("title"));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your logcat will be, all titles from all documents within your `bulletin` collection.

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for not posting my attempts. First post here on SO.

Comment: Edit: Doesn't this return the documents from the root "bulletin" and not the sub-collection in the document "bulletin"?

Comment: Yes, it returns the documents from the top-level `bulletin` collection. This is what I see in your screenshot. Isn't this what you want? If you want to get all documents within `bulletin` subcollection, you can **only** get the documents within a **single** subcollection. There is no way to get all the documents from within all subcollections in one go.

Comment: Yes I would like to get the documents in the single "bulletin" sub-collection. So something like _for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult().getDocuments().collection("bulletin"))_ which doesn't exist

Comment: You cannot do that, you should only make a `get()` on the following reference: `rootRef.collection("bulletin").document("oPpjThkRuQ9Kf5an3mGo").collection("bulletin")`

Comment: I see. I restructured my database to look like this. https://imgur.com/a/SQwmPqc I can just use the whereEqual clause to find the documents I need. Thank you.